# using md5() to generate cache keys in Zend_Cache

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-cache

I have some issues saving identifiers for cache objects in `Zend_Cache`. The `Zend_Cache` identifiers have to be really sanitized (no special chars, no spaces, etc). Some of my internal identifiers have spaces in it, so it's a problem for me to save cache objects.

I was thinking about converting the zend_cache identifier using md5() before saving it, such as:

```
$cacheId = md5(self::CACHE_PREFIX . $propertyId);

if (($address = $cache->load($cacheId)) === false) {
  .....
    $cache->save($cacheId, $address);
}
```

(Here for example, `$propertyId` might by a string with spaces)

My question is how unique are those md5 strings i'm creating? would it be possible that two of my cache objects will have the same identifier? Any suggestions?

Comment: That really depends on the uniqueness of $propertyId ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is how unique are those md5 strings i'm creating?

They are *very* unique. However, the more IDs you have the more likely is a collision (You need a *very* huge number of entries!). Also you can put the generated hashes into different "namespaces" like

```
$cacheId = 'addresses_' . md5(self::CACHE_PREFIX . $propertyId);
```

Instead of hashing you may also think about using the IDs itself. You said, that they contain some special characters. You can sanitize them e.g. using [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/base64-encode)